# Sort an array of associative arrays by the order of another array where arrays are different lengths

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

This is a tricky one to explain..

Array of categories which are in the required order

```
Array
(
[0] => products
[1] => installation
[2] => software setup
[3] => aftecare & warranty
[4] => other
)
```

and another array of questions/answers with their respective category -

```
Array
(
[installation] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [question] => Third FAQ
                [answer] => Another sample FAQ question
            )

    )

[products] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [question] => Another FAQ
                [answer] => This is a sample FAQ answer.
            )

    )
)
```

Then I need to sort this array so that the categories are in the same order as the first array. (ie products before installation)

I've attempted array_multisort() and usort(), multisort throws an array about array lengths being different and usort() requires the cmp function to return a integer, which stumped me somewhat.

Any help gratefully received.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$flipped_categories = array_flip($categories);
array_merge($flipped_categories, $product_array);
```

that should give you one array where the first array, in the correct order, now contains the FAQs within each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$sorted = array();
foreach ( $data as $name ) {
    foreach ( $data2 as $k => $part ) {
        if ($k == $name) {
            $sorted[$k] = $part;
        }
    }
}

print_r($sorted);
```

[See Demo](http://eval.in/9859)